# How does the JVM Stack Work?

Tags: java, jvm

How exactly does the JVM use a stack to run a program? I have been told that each line of code is added into a stack... but if a stack is a LIFO data-structure... wouldn't that mean that your program is run backwards? Or have I been told wrong?

Edit:

```
package test;

public class Testing {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    method2();
}

public static void method() {
    System.out.println(MyErrorHere);
} 
public static void method2() {
    method();
}
}
```

Returns the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
MyErrorHere cannot be resolved to a variable

at test.Testing.method(Testing.java:11)
at test.Testing.method2(Testing.java:14)
at test.Testing.main(Testing.java:7)
```

Each method called is added into a stack created in the main method?

Comment: It's not the instructions that are pushed onto the stack, it is their data (which on a "normal" machine would be placed in CPU registers instead of a stack).

Comment: What Hex says.  The stack serves three fairly distinct functions:  1) Keeping track of call/return sequence (where a "stack" is the obvious model), 2) providing storage for "local variables", and 3) as an "expression evaluation stack", giving instructions arranged in "reverse Polish" sequence the temporary storage they need to evaluate the "meaning" of a single statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have been told that each line of code is added into a stack...

No, that is not the case.

The JVM keeps a stack in order to keep track of data. All operations (such as addition and method invocation) use elements at the top of the stack (last in). Let's try a quick example. I generated it by creating the source as `Test.java`, compiling it with `javac Test.java`, and then executing `javah -c Test`, which subsequently displayed the bytecode. I highly encourage you to work up an example at your level, look at the bytecode, and try to analyze it or run through it in your head or with a notebook to see this for yourself.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = a + b;
        int d = c + 2;
        int e = a + d + c;
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

This is what the bytecode looks like:

```
   0: iconst_1
   1: istore_1
   2: iconst_2
   3: istore_2
   4: iload_1
   5: iload_2
   6: iadd
   7: istore_3
   8: iload_3
   9: iconst_2
  10: iadd
  11: istore        4
  13: iload_1
  14: iload         4
  16: iadd
  17: iload_3
  18: iadd
  19: istore        5
  21: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  24: iload         5
  26: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
  29: return
```

First, we push 1 onto the stack, and then pop it off the stack into a local variable. We then do the same thing again with 2. The stack frame is empty at this point.

Next step will be to evaluate `int c = a + b`. We'll push the two local variables (`a` and `b`) onto the stack:

```
2
1
[BOTTOM]
```

and execute `iadd` (called integer-add). This will cause the stack to look as follows:

```
3
[BOTTOM]
```

Instructions 7 and 8 <strike>appear to be superfluous</strike> are needed because we'll need the result for multiple additions. If we performed the first addition immediately, then that operand will be popped off the stack and unavailable to be added again. So, it is stored (popping it off the stack), and pushed onto the stack again to be used in the first of its two variable reads. After 9, the stack looks like

```
2
3
[BOTTOM]
```

Addition occurs, and we store the result (which is `d`).

We then load a again with instruction 13, and `d` with instruction 14:

```
5 (value of d)
1 (value of a)
[BOTTOM]
```

We add:

```
6 (a+d)
[BOTTOM]
```

and then push `c` onto the stack in instruction 17. Adding again gets us `e`'s value, which is stored to local variable 5.

`getstatic #2` is used to push `System.out` of type `PrintStream` to the stack. The `#2` refers to a constant pool entry in the class file. Then, the parameter that will be used for `System.out.println(int)` is pushed onto the stack:

```
9
PrintStream object that we got by evaluating System.out
[BOTTOM]
```

Then, `invokevirtual #3` with `#3` referring to the method name, is used to call the method `println(int)` of a PrintStream. The stack contains the parameter that will be passed, as well as the instance to call this method upon.

Comment: Ahh so items are constantly being popped in and popped out. So there is still some validity to what I heard first. but when a + b is called there are 3 items added into the stack then popped off.

Comment: @shinjw - Read up on "reverse Polish".  The expression `a + b` is converted to `ab+` (read left-to-right).  Operands (a and b) are pushed onto the stack, while operators (+) operate on values in the stack.  The expression `ab+` pushes a then b onto the stack, then the operator `+` pops a and b, adds them, and pushes the result back onto the stack.